# How to Push Sensor Data to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, flume

I have an Android application which transfer the GPS co-ordinates of the devices to a particular port , I need to push the data directly to HDFS in Real time so that I can Do smart advertising analysis .

Which is the tool I need to use for that?? and is there any tutorial available to push machine data directly to HDFS?

Comment: You could do it directly using  hadoop fs -put file /input whenever you recieve the file by polling or apache flume which has some other functionality which you wont need and would unnecessarily add complexity here in your case.

Comment: @almasshaikh is there any tutorial available soo that i can get started

Comment: https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

Comment: Are your users aware that you are harvesting their GPS data?

Comment: i just trying to learn Hadoop , I am very much new to BigData @Chiron

Comment: Why don't you use JMS to buffer the data first, and then push all the records together for a particular time interval(say for a day). GPS co-ordinates are small pieces of data I guess. Since HDFS is read-only, and keeping each co-ord data in a different file will be a wastage of blocks. You may follow some other approach for buffering.

Comment: @blackSmith But the application which i am talking about work with realtime data

Comment: Still you wont be able to process them real-time from HDFS !